# Existence of a smooth homotopy

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Suppose I have a contractible neighborhood $B$ inside a manifold $M$. Then I would like to justify that there exists a family of smooth maps $F_t:M\rightarrow M$ such that $F_0=id$ and $F_1(B)=\{p\}$, where $p\in M$.

We know that $i:B\rightarrow M$ is homotopic to a constant map but other than this I am bit lost on how to get the homotopy,since I am not sure I can use the homotopy extension property , and then how to make it smooth.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your neighborhood closed? Otherwise, you have things like the torus minus the wedge of circles which is a dense contractible subset which cannot be collapsed without sending everything to the collapse point.

Comment: The author from the book I was reading this does not specify if it was closed or not @ConnorMalin

Comment: Do you need this for *any* $B$, or for, say, small enough contractible open subsets $B$, so that you can for instance assume that there is some $B’ \supset B$ open subset of $M$ such that $(B,B’) \cong (B^n,3B^n)$?

Comment: I think small enought contractible open sets is enough. @Mindlack

Comment: @No clue: If so, then show (with my notations) that there is a smooth sequence of smooth maps $f_t:3B^n \rightarrow 3B^n$ such that $f_0=id$, $f_1(x)=0$ if $|x| \leq 1$ and $f_t(x)=x$ if $|x| \geq 2$. The $f_t$ are thus a smooth sequence of smooth maps $B’ \rightarrow B’$ that contracts $B$ to a point while being the identity of a neighborhood of $\partial B’$, so they naturally extend as maps $M \rightarrow M$.

Comment: @Mindlack This should be an official answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, I’m turning my hint into a fully-fledged solution.

First, as Connor Malin’s comment points out, the statement is false in general, because some manifolds can have a dense contractible open subset. A general example would be any compact manifold which has a finite cellular decomposition with a single top-dimensional cell (the interior of which is open, dense and contractible) – real and complex projective spaces, spheres, tori are in this case.

A natural restriction (not the only one) is if we require $B$ to be small enough. If $B$ is small enough, we can assume that there is a smooth, open, injective map $\pi: 3B^n \rightarrow M$ which is a diffeomorphism into its image $B’$ and such that $\pi(B^n) \supset B$.

Let $\psi:[0,3] \rightarrow [0,1]$ as a smooth function such that $\psi([0,1])=\{0\},\psi([2,3])=\{1\}$. Let, for $0 \leq t \leq 1$, $g_t: x \in 3B^n \longmapsto (1-t+t\psi(\|x\|))x \in 3B^n$. Then if $\|x\| \geq 2$, $f_t(x)=x$; $f_0(x)=x$ for any $x$; and $f_1(x)=0$ if $\|x\|=1$.

Define, for $q \in M$, $f_t(q)=q$ if $q \notin B’$, and $f_t(q)=\pi(g_t(\pi^{-1}(q)))$ if $q \in B’$. Then $f_t$ is a smooth sequene of smooth maps $M \rightarrow M$; $f_0=id$ and $f_1(B)=\{\pi(0)\}$.